# Hausdorff, regular but not metrizable

Tags: general-topology

I´m wondering if there is a topology that is Hausdorff and regular but not metrizable. Someone can help me?

Comment: Take a product of uncountably many compact intervals, $[0,\,1]^{[0,\,1]}$ for example. It's Hausdorff, and compact by Tikhonov, hence regular, but it's not metrizable (it isn't first countable).

Comment: Let me recommend a book, [Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) by Lynn Steen and J. Arthur Steenbach Jr.  A good reference for many such questions.

Comment: Austin Mohr's Spacebook that I linked to incorporates a lot of the examples from Steen and Seebach, incidentally.

Comment: $\beta \Bbb N $

Comment: The Sorgenfrey plane is not normal, but is Tychonoff as the square of the Sorgenfrey line, which is Tychonoff. By the way: Hausdorff + regular is also called $T_3$.

Comment: Slightly simplifying Daniel Fisher's comment, take the product of uncountably many copies of a discrete space of two points.

Comment: Thanks for replies.  I made This question because i have a topology based on a generalized metric that is hausdorff, regular and first countable but not metrizable. After seen the  above examples, i`m trying to prove that my topology is also normal. Thus, i  have to ask: such topology (T4, first countable and non metrizable) exists?

Answer (score 5):

The [Long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is an example, along with a lot of other things here at [Austin Mohr's spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146).

Answer (score 0):

The first uncountable ordinal space is a good example. It's sequentially compact but not compact, so can't be metrizable.